# Compartir contenido web en Google+

Tags: html, google-plus, google+

¿Alguien sabe cómo puedo compartir contenido de mi pagina web en Google+? El problema es que es contenido que se genera dinámicamente, me gustaría hacer algo como lo que hace Facebook, que me deja personalizar el título o la imagen entre otros parámetros.

¿Alguna idea de cómo puedo hacerlo para Google+ sin usar los tags de `<meta>`?
Actualmente tengo algo así, esto sólo me comparte la url, me gustaría incluir la descripción y la imagen de un artículo.

```
<a class="btn btn-default fa fa-google-plus" href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=http://mipagina.com/mipaginaseccion/articulos.php" data-size="large" target="v" onclick="window.open(this.href, this.target, 'width=400,height=400'); return false"></a>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Según la [documentación oficial de Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/#sharelink-endpoint), a la URL sólo se le pueden pasar dos parámetros y ninguno de ellos es descripción, título o imagen. Los únicos parámetros disponibles a día de hoy son:

- `url`: la URL de la página a compartir. El valor debe estar codificado (*urlencode*).
- `hl`: el código del locale (pareja idioma-región) que usará Google+ en la página de compartir.

Tendrás que optar por incluir algún tipo de metadata en la página para que los valores que quieres se muestren a la hora de compartir. Aunque [como se explica en esta otra página](https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/#documentation), esa metadata no tiene por qué ir en las etiquetas `meta`. Dejo aquí un resumen de las opciones que menciona allí:

## Utilizar microdata de Schema.org

Si la página está anotada con [microdata de Schema.org](http://schema.org/docs/gs.html), el diálogo de compartir de Google+ usará el nombre, imagen y descripción que encuentre en los tipo especificados en schema.org. Éste es el **método recomendado en la página de Google** porque ellos también usan esta microdata en sus páginas y en las búsquedas.

La idea es que añadas el atributo `itemprop` con el valor: `name` (para el título de la página), `description` (para la etiqueta que contenga la descripción), e `image` en la imagen que quieras que acompañe al post:

```
<!-- actualiza la etiqueta body para que incluya itemscope e itemtype. -->
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
  ...
  <h1 itemprop="name">Esto será el título</h1>
  <img itemprop="image" src="http://mi.web.com/imagen.jpg" /> <!-- ésta será la imagen -->
  <p itemprop="description">Este párrafo será la descripción.</p>
```

O si prefieres hacerlo en la cabecera, también podrías hacerlo usando estas etiquetas:

```
<!-- actualiza la etiqueta html para que incluya itemscope e itemtype. -->
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">

  <head>

    <meta itemprop="name" content="Esto será el título">
    <meta itemprop="description" content="Este párrafo será la descripción.">
    <meta itemprop="image" content="http://mi.web.com/imagen.jpg">
```

---

## Utilizar el protocolo Open Graph

Me imagino que estas son las etiquetas `meta` que mencionabas en la pregunta diciendo que querías evitar. La idea básica para este método es añadir la meta-información en la cabecera usando las etiquetas `meta` especificando propiedades Open Graph (`og:`).

Un ejemplo de cómo hacerlo, añade esto a tu cabecera:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Esto será el título" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://mi.web.com/imagen.jpg" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Este párrafo será la descripción." />
```

---

## Utilizar etiquetas `meta`

Parecido al sistema anterior, pero sin necesidad de usar Open Graph. Simplemente usando la meta-etiqueta para descripción, y el título de la página para título del post. Un problema de este método es que **no se puede especificar la imagen**, entonces Google intentará identificar la más adecuada para mostrar cuando se comparta la página.

Así, sólo tendrías que asegurarte de que la página tenga lo siguiente en la cabecera:

```
<title>Esto será el título</title>
<meta name="description" content="Este párrafo será la descripción." />
```

---

## No hacer nada

Si no puedes (o no quieres) implementar ninguno de los métodos anteriores, entonces Google procesará la página y elegirá todo por ti los que decida son título, descripción e imagen más adeacuados.

Ni que decir tiene, **este método no está recomendado** porque es el peor: pierdes control sobre cómo se verá la página en Google+ y cómo se verá el +Snippet.

Comment: Hola Alvaro, pero cómo quedaría construido el link para compartir ? Por lo que he leído, el protocolo Open Graph también me serviría para compartir en facebook...

Comment: @MNibor el enlace en un href sería algo como: `https://plus.google.com/share?url={URL}` (donde `{URL}` es la página que quieras compartir en Google+. OpenGraph es muy útil porque funciona con Google+, Facebook, Skype... y muchos otras redes sociales y programas de mensajería. Y no necesitas un enlace especial, solo compartir la URL en ellas y ya se encargarán de leer los datos de OpenGraph y mostrarlos.

Comment: si si... fue agregar las lineas de OG y reconoció todo de forma impecable... tengo problemas con las fotos, pero creo que es por la resolución mala de algunas me parece

Comment: @MNibor ¿Qué tamaño tienen? Con OpenGraph puedes poner más de una imagen con diferentes dimensiones (en cuyo caso no sé cuál se elegirá). En [este enlace de Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices/#images) puedes ver recomendaciones para el tamaño de las imágenes.