# Micro datos enriquecidos

Tags: html5

estoy estudiando micro datos enriquecidos, pero la verdad no entiendo mucho del tema, por lo cual estoy siguiendo un ejemplo, este [ejemplo](http://falasco.org/microdatos-html5-y-seo).

La cosa es que solo tengo preguntar por ejemplo para que diablos sirve meterle eso a mi web, y segun vi estos son los atributos
pero como se usan? en itemprop?
[image: Propiedades]

Entonces si es así cual es la funcion de itemscope, y la de de itemtype, y por que en itemtype se le envia una url?

tengo este codigo de ejemplo sacado de la pagina que les mostre:

```
<section itemtype="http://schema.org/Person" itemscope="">
<img width="200" height="200" alt="Roxana Falasco" src="http://falasco.org/photo.jpg" itemprop="photo">
<h1>Información de contacto</h1>
<dl>
    <dt>Nombre</dt>
    <dd itemprop="name">Roxana Falasco</dd>
    <dt>Position</dt>
    <dd><span itemprop="title">FrontEnd Developer</span> for
        <span itemprop="affiliation">Resto-In</span>
    </dd>
    <dt>Dirección Postal</dt>
    <dd itemprop="address" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Address">
        <span itemprop="street-address">100 Mi Calle</span><br />
        <span itemprop="locality">Barcelona</span>,
        <span itemprop="region">Barcelona</span>
        <span itemprop="postal-code">08080</span><br />
        <span itemprop="country-name">España</span>
    </dd>
</dl>
```

[image: Errores]
y no entiendo esas alertas y errores

Answer (score 3):

Yo nunca he usado el formato **html** porque me parece un coñazo enorme, ademas de que estropea mucho la legibilidad del código, aunque he visto que tienes algunos fallos independientemente del formato.

Te recomiendo que visites la web: **https://schema.org** cada vez que quieras trabajar con tarjetas enriquecidas, para este caso concreto tendrías que haber consultado:

https://schema.org/Person

https://schema.org/PostalAddress

Respecto a la utilidad de cada atributo, nunca he trabajado con tu formato, asi que te aconsejo que contrastes la información, pues esto es lo que creo solo, **itemscope** creo que es para indicar que esa etiqueta es un elemento, osea que Google debe de prestarle atención porque puede tener de los otros atributos.

**itemtype** Es la url del Schema al que pertenece ese elemento, y **itemprop** es la propiedad a la que ese elemento da valor, las propiedades válidas tienes que mirarlas en la pagina **Schema** que te puse antes.

Una alternativa que te propongo más limpia es el uso de **JSON-LD** que lo tienes que escribir en la etiqueta `<script>` dentro de `<head>`

```
 <script type="application/ld+json">
{
      "@context": "http://schema.org/",
      "@type": "Person",
      "name": "Roxana Falasco",
      "jobTitle": "Front End Developer",
      "image": "http://falasco.org/photo.jpg",    
      "affiliation": {
        "@type": "Organization",
        "name": "Resto-In"
      },
      "address": {
        "@type": "PostalAddress",
        "streetAddress": "100 mi calle",
        "addressLocality": "Barcelona",
        "addressRegion": "Barcelona",
        "postalCode": "18088",
        "addressCountry": "España"
      }
}
</script>
```

Para hacerlo con **html** como tu lo tienes sería:

```
<section itemtype="http://schema.org/Person" itemscope="">
<img width="200" height="200" alt="Roxana Falasco" src="http://falasco.org/photo.jpg" itemprop="image">
<h1>Información de contacto</h1>
<dl>
    <dt>Nombre</dt>
    <dd itemprop="name">Roxana Falasco</dd>
    <dt>Position</dt>
    <dd><span itemprop="jobTitle">FrontEnd Developer</span> for
        <span itemprop="affiliation">Resto-In</span>
    </dd>
    <dt>Dirección Postal</dt>
    <dd itemprop="address" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
        <span itemprop="streetAddress">100 Mi Calle</span><br />
        <span itemprop="addressLocality">Barcelona</span>,
        <span itemprop="addressRegion">Barcelona</span>
        <span itemprop="postalCode">08080</span><br />
        <span itemprop="addressCountry">España</span>
    </dd>
</dl>
</section>
```

Respecto a la utilidad, sirve para facilitar a **Google** la **información** de forma que el pueda entenderla más rápida y fácilmente, lo cual puede traducirse a veces en una mejora del **SEO** y en algunos casos concretos también ofrece una mejora a nivel de usuario, pues sobre todo en dispositivos móviles, cuando un usuario busca algo concreto, las paginas que tienen micro-datos suelen salir con distinciones, el caso más destacado es el de las **Recipes** mira este ejemplo:

[image: Tarjetas enriquecidas recipes]

Espero haberte ayudado, y cualquier duda no dudes en preguntar ;)

Comment: Por ahora, tengo una pregunta, si lo hago con el json, no le debo agregar nada a el sitio web es decir, le agrego ese script para todos las veces que lo necesite y listo, ósea si tengo varias personas o artículos, pero de resto no debo hacer nada mas?

Comment: No, cada pagina tendría que tener su json propio, por ejemplo si tienes otra pagina con otra persona llamada **Pepe** que trabaja de **cocinero**, y vive en **mallorca**, tendrías que hacer un json concreto para esa pagina, sino estarías diciéndole a Google que  en todas las paginas están los datos de todas las personas, lo cual sería erróneo. Debes agregar el script en aquellas paginas que tengan datos, con los datos concretos de esa pagina(pueden ser mas cosas aparte de personas, como recetas)

Answer (score 0):

**¿Para qué sirve? ¿cómo se usan?**

Los microdatos sirven para añadir significado a tu contenido. Realmente no son para ayudar a la gente a entender mejor el contenido, sino para ayudar a los usuarios no humanos (p.e. navegadores, crawlers, lectores de pantalla, etc.) para que puedan dar sentido a ese contenido.

Algunos buscadores y redes sociales usan los microdatos para extraer información adicional que utilizarán para indexar mejor tus páginas o para sacar información relevante que será mostrada (por ejemplo, [Google prefiere microdatos para compartir las páginas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/5968/250)).

En HTML, se pueden usar añadiendo atributos a etiquetas y contenedores para identificar. Con `itemtype` se indicaría el esquema usado (qué tipo de datos va a ir contenido) y con `itemprop` se indicaría qué es ese dato particular.

La idea es añadir contenido semántico. Datos sobre los datos (metadatos y metainformación) que facilite el análisis e identificación del contenido de la página web.

**¿Cuál es la función de itemscope, y la de itemtype, y por qué en itemtype se envía una url?**

Como mencionaba en el párrafo anterior, con `itemtype` se indica el esquema que se va a usar. Dicho esquema define el tipo de datos que se van a contener, y la jerarquía de los mismos (p.e. en el ejemplo que pones hay una persona que contiene una dirección). Es una URL a la definición del esquema en [Schema.org](https://schema.org/).

[`itemscope`](https://schema.org/docs/gs.html#microdata_itemscope_itemtype) se usa para identificar cada una de las instancias a las que aplican los datos del esquema. O lo que es lo mismo: el ámbito (*scope*) de los mismos. Es un atributo que no necesita valor (no hace falta poner `itemscope=""`, con `itemscope` es suficiente).

---

En el ejemplo que pones:

```
<section itemtype="http://schema.org/Person" itemscope="">
<img width="200" height="200" alt="Roxana Falasco" src="http://falasco.org/photo.jpg" itemprop="photo">
<h1>Información de contacto</h1>
<dl>
    <dt>Nombre</dt>
    <dd itemprop="name">Roxana Falasco</dd>
    <dt>Position</dt>
    <dd><span itemprop="title">FrontEnd Developer</span> for
        <span itemprop="affiliation">Resto-In</span>
    </dd>
    <dt>Dirección Postal</dt>
    <dd itemprop="address" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Address">
        <span itemprop="street-address">100 Mi Calle</span><br />
        <span itemprop="locality">Barcelona</span>,
        <span itemprop="region">Barcelona</span>
        <span itemprop="postal-code">08080</span><br />
        <span itemprop="country-name">España</span>
    </dd>
</dl>
```

Con el `itemtype="http://schema.org/Person"` se está indicando que el contenido de la sección es una Persona, y luego con los `itemprop` se dan detalles específicos de esa persona: su foto (`itemprop="photo"`), nombre (`itemprop="name"`), lugar de trabajo (`itemprop="affiliation"`) y puesto (`itemprop="title"`)...

Y luego para esa persona se indica una dirección (`itemprop="address"`) que a su vez tiene un esquema propio (por eso además del `itemprop` se añade un nuevo `itemtype` de tipo Address, que por cierto es incorrecto porque debería ser PostalAddress) con información más detallada (nombre de calle, ciudad, código postal, etc).

Esa información podría ser obvia para un ser humano al ver la página, pero no ser tan obvia para una máquina, que podría detectar algunos datos (un número de teléfono por su formato) pero no otros (¿qué tiene que ver FrontEnd Developer con Resto-In o Roxana Falasco?). Gracias a los microdatos esa información es fácil de catalogar para la máquina: Roxana Falasco es una persona que trabaja de FrontEnd Developer en Resto-in.